# How to run the two branch code parallelly in the jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, newman

I need to run the newman code parallelly in pipeline. I am facing the issue while running the newman code:

```
parallel firstBranch: {
node{

       sh "newman run 'XYZ.json'  --insecure"    


    }
},
secondBranch
    node{
sh "newman run 'XYX.json'  --insecure"
}    
},
failFast: true|false
```

I am getting the error code as:

```
hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.jenkinsci.plugins.docker.workflow.Docker.call() is applicable for argument types: (org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsClosure2) values: [org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), each(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure), grep()
```

Answer (score 0):

you have a syntax mistakes in your pipeline like
secondBranch without ": {"
you can try like this example taken from Jenkins documentation :

```
   stages {
    stage('Run Tests') {
        parallel {
            stage('Test On Windows') {
                agent {
                    label "windows"
                }
                steps {
                    bat "run-tests.bat"
                }
                post {
                    always {
                        junit "**/TEST-*.xml"
                    }
                }
            }
            stage('Test On Linux') {
                agent {
                    label "linux"
                }
                steps {
                    sh "run-tests.sh"
                }
                post {
                    always {
                        junit "**/TEST-*.xml"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```